# Does interpolation work in event bindng?

Tags: aurelia

Does interpolation work on event-binding?  I tried the following without success:

```
<button type="button" click.delegate="${action}()">${action}</button>
```

action is a VM variable set to one of "edit","add","cancel".  There exist VM functions: edit, add, and cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble trying to use interpolation with event-binding. I had much better luck referencing the VM as a function instead.

Say you had action as a property of your view model. You could set the value of that property to the correct method based on the model or some UI action, and then when the action is called as a method, the correct add/edit/cancel method is called.

inside the view-model (es6):

```
setAction(method) {
  if(method === "edit") {
    this.action = this.editMethod;
  } else if(method === "add") {
    this.action = this.addMethod;
  } else {
    this.action = this.cancelMethod;
  }
}

editMethod() {
  alert("edit");
}

addMethod() {
  alert("add");
}

cancelMethod() {
  alert("cancel/default");
}
```

inside the template:

```
<button click.delegate="setAction('edit')">Use Edit Method</button>
<button click.delegate="setAction('add')">Use Add Method</button>
<button click.delegate="setAction('cancel')">Use Cancel Method</button>
<button click.delegate="action()">action</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Danyow provided the answer on the github issues forum for aurelia-binding.

```
<button click.delegate="$this[action]()">${action}</button>
```